# CircleCI cannot specify region to deploy to in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, continuous-integration

I have been tying to update a deployment in a GKE cluster using CircleCI. I was able to make container build and upload to GCR work just fine.

But I could not find a way to specify the GCP region when authenticating using the command such as `gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials $K8S_CLUSTER --region=$MY_REGION` for updating my Kubernetes deployment.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
gcloud --quiet config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
gcloud --quiet config set compute/region $MY_REGION
gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials $K8S_CLUSTER --region $MY_REGION
kubectl set image deployment/$DEPLOYMENT $APP_NAME=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$APP_NAME:v2

Updated property [core/project].
Updated property [compute/region].
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) unrecognized arguments:
  --region
  asia-southeast1
Exited with code 2
```

We know there's an argument called `--region` to specify the region.

```
root@host# gcloud container clusters get-credentials -h
Usage: gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --internal-ip | --region | --zone

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud container clusters get-credentials --help
root@host#
```

Why doesn't CircleCI's version of gcloud does not support this parameter?

I even tried Orbs [gcr](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/gcp-gcr) and [gke](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/gcp-gke), and the same error happens.

Comment: Try to use --zone=name_of_region, I use this and works gcloud container clusters get-credentials mycluster --zone europe-west3 --project=myproject

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the error "ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=400, message='zone' field cannot be used to access GKE regional clusters. Use 'name' or 'parent' fields instead.
Exited with code 1"

Comment: Is this issue still valid? What GKE version did you use?

Comment: @PjoterS sorry not anymore. I remember being absolutely furious with this that I switched over to GitLab CI (and self-hosted runner) and kubectl (instead of gcloud).

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old (1 year, 5 months) and many changes might appear to `CircleCI` and `GKE`.

Based on error output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) unrecognized arguments:
  --region
  asia-southeast1
```

It looks like `GKE` couldn't execute this command.

### Tests

In test I've created proper environment variables like: `$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID`, `$MY_REGION`, `$K8S_CLUSTER` and `hello-world` test deployment.

```
$ gcloud --quiet config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud --quiet config set compute/region $MY_REGION
Updated property [compute/region].
```

Next step was to use `get-credentials` information.

Common mistake is that users think that `--region` and `--zone` have the same meaning which is not true. More details can be found in Documentation [Identifying a region or zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#identifying_a_region_or_zone)

While `--region` flag was used, cluster needs to be a `Regional` cluster not `Zonal`.

Output while cluster (cluster-1) is `Zonal`:

```
$ gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials $K8S_CLUSTER --region $MY_REGION
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=404, message=Not found: projects/project/locations/asia-southeast1/clusters/cluster-1.
Could not find [cluster-1] in [asia-southeast1].
Did you mean [cluster-1] in [asia-southeast1-a]?
```

Please keep in mind that this is the newest version. Older versions might have different warning/error content.

But if you would use `Regional` cluster (cluster-2)

```
$ gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials $K8S_CLUSTER --region $MY_REGION
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for cluster-2.
```

Editing deployment:

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/hello-world hello-app=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
deployment.apps/hello-world image updated
```

### Conclusion

While you are specifying `--region` or `--zone` please remember to check if cluster was created as `Zonal` or `Regional`, otherwise, you will encounter `Error`.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, thanks for the update. I understand you are affiliated with GKE and I appreciate you extending your help. Reading back on this question, I assume that at that time, `CircleCI`'s version of gcloud was very old and did not have support for the `--region` parameter, otherwise it would have spit out an error other than `unrecognized arguments`, regardless if at that time I thought --region and --size were the same or not (although I doubt this). If that's not the case, then it was a gcloud issue and there should have been a more meaningful error other than 'unrecognized argument'.